# How to use is not null sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**my SQL CODE**

```
     $sqlNull = "SELECT primary_maths ,primary_enviornment ,primary_english 
    ,primary_sinhala ,primary_tamil ,p_special_english ,p_a ,p_b ,p_c ,p_d ,p_e 
    ,p_f ,p_g ,ol_maths ,ol_maths_paperClass ,ol_english ,ol_sinhala ,ol_tamil 
    ,ol_science ,ol_history ,ol_commerce ,ol_art ,al_class_chemesty 
,al_class_physics ,al_class_combindmaths ,al_class_bioscience ,al_class_economics 
    ,al_class_businessStudies ,al_class_account ,al_class_sinhala 
    ,al_class_logic ,al_class_buddhist ,scouting ,sp_eng ,rev_a 
    ,rev_b ,rev_c ,rev_d ,rev_e ,rev_f ,rev_g ,rev_h ,rev_i ,rev_j 
    ,o_a ,o_b ,o_c ,o_d ,o_e ,o_f ,o_g ,o_h ,o_i ,o_j 
    FROM Persons WHERE reg_id='$search' IS NOT NULL";
```

**My PHP CODE**

```
$sqlSubject=$dbconnect->prepare($sqlNull);
$sqlSubject->execute();

$resultFull=$sqlSubject->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($resultFull);
```

now my output is

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

How to use ***WHERE Clause*** with parameter and the ***IS NOT NULL***.I jsut have 59 columns and someof them contain ***NULL*** values.So i want to remove them when  output($resultFull) coming from database.In other words i want to select where  values ***IS NOT NULL***

Comment: you can't alter the field list based conditions

Comment: i didn't get it.can you exlane ?

Comment: you have to put `IS NOT NULL` in it's own expression. You can check if a value is not null by saying `WHERE COLUMN IS NOT NULL`. You can't however change the list of columns you select based on if the values are null. You can however check if a column is null and pull a different value if it is. check out [ifnull()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

Comment: Normalize your data. An RDBMS table is NOT a spreadsheet!

Answer (score 0):

If you want an queryresult where none of the selected cols are null you have to alter you WHERE with an addional "and  is not null" for every col. Just like Niels Keurentjes, Manish Jangir and Bailey S wrote above.